# Rails not loading fixtures in test with similar names with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have 3 classes with STI and I want to load fixtures for each:

`Employee`

`Admin < Employee`

`OtherEmployee < Employee`

My test_helper files has `fixtures :all`

and the fixtures are in:

`employees.yml`
`admins.yml`
`other_employees.yml`

and yet only the data from `other_employees.yml` is loaded into the database. Any idea why or how to fix this?

Fixtures:

```
#employees.yml
one: 
  id: 1
  name: Name1
  full_name: FName1
  type: Admin

two: 
  name: Name2
  full_name: FName2
  type: Admin

three:
  name: Name3
  full_name: FName3
  type: OtherEmployee

#admins.yml

adminone:
   name: Admin1
   full_name: FAdmin1
   type: Admin

admintwo:
   name: Admin2
   full_name: FAdmin2
   type: Admin

#other_employees.yml

oeone:
   name: Oemp1
   full_name: FOemp1
   type: OtherEmployee

oetwo:
   name: Oemp2
   full_name: FOemp2
   type: OtherEmployee
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Rails are you using? It appears that this was a bug and was fixed in Rails 5 and 4.2

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18492

There is also some info in the last comment that may be helpful.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18492#issuecomment-218479248

> For anyone still running into this problem you need to add a type
>   attribute to your fixtures, which represents the STI attribute on your
>   model. For the provided example this would be:
>
> ```
> #teachers.yml
> presto:
>   name: Test Teacher
>   type: Teacher
> #students.yml
> testo:
>   name: Test Person
>   teacher: presto
>   type: Student
> ```

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.6. If I try as above, the database seems to only take 1 file. Specifically, whichever is later alphabetically, which might be a clue.

Comment: Can you post what your fixture files look like?

Comment: Shouldn't the `type` field in "employees.yml" be `Employee` instead of `Admin` or `OtherEmployee`

Comment: Possible. I've commented out admins.yml and other_employees.yml so that my tests work by only pulling from employees.yml. Also in my world an employee is either an Admin or an OtherEmployee. Currently type "Employee" doesn't exist.